# Getting Exception in basic webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

I have made a webservice which is simply displaying a user data from a database. but i am keep on getting this exception when i run the client side.

> Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,110]

/////////////////////This is webservice code////////////////////////////////

@WebMethod(operationName = "viewUserData")

```
public ArrayList viewUserData() {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "";
    //ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    try {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@p5";
        Connection connection = null;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "backconnect", "backconnect");
        query = "select * from users";
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){
            /*HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put("USER_ID", rs.getString("USER_ID"));
            map.put("NAME", rs.getString("NAME"));
            map.put("SHORT_NAME", rs.getString("SHORT_NAME"));
            map.put("PASSWORD", rs.getString("PASSWORD"));*/
            SetData sdata = new SetData();
            sdata.setUSER_ID(rs.getString("USER_ID"));
            sdata.setNAME(rs.getString("NAME"));
            sdata.setSHORT_NAME(rs.getString("SHORT_NAME"));
            sdata.setPASSWORD(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
            /*list.add(rs.getString("USER_ID"));
            list.add(rs.getString("NAME"));
            list.add(rs.getString("SHORT_NAME"));
            list.add(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));*/
            list.add(sdata);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}
```

SetData is a java bean
////////////////////This is client code///////////////////

```
    package1.GetUserDataService service = new package1.GetUserDataService();
package1.GetUserData port = service.getGetUserDataPort();
// TODO process result here
java.util.List<java.lang.Object> result = port.viewUserData();
out.println("Result = "+result);
```

I am stuck into this. How to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd try to do is work out whether this is really a client error or a server error.

Use [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) to intercept the traffic from the client to the server, and check whether the SOAP request looks valid.

You haven't said whether you get the exception itself on the client side or the server side, so it's possible that the *request* is getting there okay, but the client isn't reading the *response* properly.

EDIT: To simplify things, you may want to just hard code some data for the moment. It doesn't *look* like the problem is within the database code itself, so make diagnostics easier by just removing all of that - just hard code a couple of names to return... you might even want to change it to return an `int`, just to see whether the problem is using an `ArrayList`.

Comment: on this line of client side, it is throwing an exception                            java.util.List<java.lang.Object> result = port.viewUserData();

Comment: @Java_NewBie: The client side may end up reporting the error either way, but you should be able to see what's going and coming back.

Comment: @Java_NewBie: in addition to Jon recommentdations: test the webservice with [soapUI](http://www.eviware.com/soapUI/soapui-products-overview.html) - if *that* works and the messages look good, then investigate in the client.

Comment: @Jon....I have tried it by replacing  return type of String and it works fine but when i use ArrayList and pass any object or hashmap in it it still giving an exception. furthermore, if i pass a string in ArrayList it also works fine. but i think it is only giving exception when i put objects or hashmap in arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you may want to return a WebRowSet from your web service if your jdbc provider supports it.
Here is an example

```
import javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet;
import com.sun.rowset.WebRowSetImpl; // Reference implementation
...
// get ResultSet rs from db
WebRowSet webrowset = new WebRowSetImpl();
webrowset.populate(rs);
// return webrowset from web service
```

This way you can get rid of SetData java bean that you are using.

Comment: what if i could do this.                              > HashMap map = new HashMap();
            map.put("USER_ID", rs.getString("USER_ID"));
            map.put("NAME", rs.getString("NAME"));
            map.put("SHORT_NAME", rs.getString("SHORT_NAME"));
            map.put("PASSWORD", rs.getString("PASSWORD"));  and then add this map into list but still it is giving an error, i have tried your solution but it isi'nt deploying.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and I solved it by adding some missing artifacts to my project. It seems that cxf is not able to fill the payload in the message on the client side due to this missing artifacts:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
<version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ezmorph</groupId>
        <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fife</groupId>
        <artifactId>rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>143</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jtidy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
        <version>r820</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

PS: i used unit test class to call the WS
cxf version: 2.4

Hope it helps!